# Service connect, Response for preflight is invalid (301) redirect.

Tags: 7, services, javascript

I'm trying to authenticate with headless drupal (hybride app running localy on my computer) to a drupal (7.34) website. I installed cors en services en enabled all the necesary endpoints to authenticate en connect to the drupal website.

I managed to get it to work on a previous project. But on this, i get stuck at the connect step (see pictures below). Response for preflight is invalid (redirect). I have absolutly no clue where to look to solve this problem. Can someone point me in the right direction? Couldn't find much information about this error on my good friend google.

[image: authentication to drupal]
[image: header part 1]
[image: header part 2]

Comment: Sounds like you have a module like Global Redirect enabled, trying disabling it (and any related modules).

Comment: Thx! Global Redirect is causing the problem. Apparently request of the type 'OPTIONS' won't we be rewritten but other types (GET,...) will.

Comment: Check out this issue for a patch to allow you to still use Global Redirect, but ignore it on certain paths: https://www.drupal.org/node/1438584